# MS Word fonts enlargement

Tags: microsoft-word

Is it possible to change the default font MS Word from the set default (11) to something bigger?

Comment: For what version of Word?

Answer (score 6):

but of course, just change the default template, more here:

**[How to set the default font in Word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291291)**

APPLIES TO

```
* Microsoft Word 2002 Standard Edition
* Microsoft Office Word 2003
* Microsoft Office Word 2007
```

Answer (score 0):

In Word 2007, you can just write click on style Normal, choose "Modify", change the font size, and then select "Home>Change Styles>Set As Default".

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

1. Find out where the .dot or .dotx file is located.
2. Start MS Word, then open the template. (note: not an instance of the template)
3. Modify the Normal style.
4. Save.